# variable values filling not working in bash

Tags: bash, variable, here-document

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
$db=DB
$H=6973
$cov=38
for i in $(find . -type f -name "*.*.las");
do
  cat <<EOF
  #qsub <<EOF
#!/bin/bash -l

#PBS -N DASqv
#PBS -l walltime=48:00:00
#PBS -j oe
#PBS -l mem=30G
#PBS -l ncpus=1
#PBS -M m.lorenc@qut.edu.au
##PBS -m bea

cd \$PBS_O_WORKDIR

source activate thegenemyers

DAStrim=$(DASqv -v -H$H -c$cov $db $i | grep Recommend - | sed "s|Recommend ||g" - | sed "s|'||g" -)

DAStrim $db $i 

EOF

done
```

Unfortunately, I got this error:

```
sh Dascrubber_pbs.sh

DASqv: -H '' argument is not an integer
  #qsub <<EOF
#!/bin/bash -l

#PBS -N DASqv
#PBS -l walltime=48:00:00
#PBS -j oe
#PBS -l mem=30G
#PBS -l ncpus=1
#PBS -M m.lorenc@qut.edu.au
##PBS -m bea

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR

source activate thegenemyers

DAStrim=

DAStrim  ./DB.309.las
```

I would have expected to see e.g. `DAStrim=$(DASqv -v -H6973 -c38 DB ./DB.82.las | grep Recommend - | sed "s|Recommend ||g" - | sed "s|'||g" -)`.

What did I miss?

Comment: `$H=6973` isn't an assignment in bash (and related shells): use `H=6973`

Comment: As well as what @steeldriver said about variable assignments, you can also improve your use of `sed`.  there's no need for `grep | sed | sed` here - one sed command can do it all `DAStrim=$(DASqv -v -H$H -c$cov $db $i | sed -n -e "/Recommend / { s/Recommend //; s/'//g ; p }"`.   More importantly, see [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice)

Comment: In addition, when you are running the script as `sh Dascrubber_pbs.sh`, you are not necessarily executing it as a bash script. What language is assumed here, depends on how sh is defined (where it is pointing to).

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues:

1. As [steeldriver pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/420551/80216#comment756112_420551),
   assignments in shells (other than C shell derivatives) look like

   ```
   variable=value
   ```

   not

   ```
   $variable=value
   ```
2. If a here-document’s delimiter string is not quoted,
   the contents of the here-document are interpreted (expanded). 
   So you shouldn’t be expecting to see `DAStrim=$(DASqv -v -H6973 ...)`, you should be expecting to see `DAStrim=whatever_the_output_of_DASqv_is`. 
   If, for some reason, you wanted to see the command,
   you should quote the `EOF`, or any of its characters
   (so you could use `'EOF'`, `"EOF"`, `\EOF`, or assorted other variations),
   or escape the `$`. 
   For example,

   ```
   $ WORKDIR=/tmp
    
   $ i=foobar.las
    
   $ cat << EOF
   cd \$WORKDIR
   ls -l "$i"
   today=$(date)
   EOF
   cd $WORKDIR                             (output)
   ls -l "foobar.las"
   today=Tue, Jan 30, 2018  1:27:42 AM
    
   $ cat << 'EOF'
   cd \$WORKDIR                            (same input as above)
   ls -l "$i"
   today=$(date)
   EOF
   cd \$WORKDIR                            (output)
   ls -l "$i"
   today=$(date)
    
   $
   ```